# Python Mail program issue

Tags: python, email, smtp, gmail, spam

I'm trying to send emails to mails in a `.txt` file. but mails doesnt delivered after first mail. I get the following error :

> 550 5.7.1 [209.85.220.41] This message is not RFC 5322 compliant, the
> issue is: duplicate headers. To reduce the amount of spam sent to
> Gmail, this message has been blocked. Please review RFC 5322
> specifications for more information.
> gv45-20020a1709072bed00b007b284329e31sor3288924ejc.70 - gsmtp

mails.txt lines is like:

```
Name,Surname,name@gmail.com
```

Thats my code :

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import sys

mesaj = MIMEMultipart()

with open("mails.txt","r",encoding="utf-8") as file:
    mailler=file.readlines()

for i in mailler:
    try:
        kisi=i.split(",")
        kisi[1].strip("\n")
        mesaj["From"]="MY MAİL HERE"
        mesaj["To"]=kisi[1]
        mesaj["Subject"]="SMTP Toplu Mail Denemesi"
        yazı=kisi[0]+"Bu Maili Görmezden Gelin"
        icerik=MIMEText(yazı,"plain")
        mesaj.attach(icerik)
        mail=smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
        mail.ehlo()
        mail.starttls()
        mail.login("my mail",
                   "my mail app password here")
        mail.sendmail(mesaj["From"],mesaj["To"],mesaj.as_string())
        print(kisi[0]," Adlı Kişiye Mail Başarıyla Gönderildi")
        mail.close()
    except:
        sys.stderr.write("Mail Gönderilemedi.")
        sys.stderr.flush()
```

I cant send more than 1 mail.

Comment: `mail.sendmail(mesaj["From"],mesaj["To"],mesaj.as_string())` The output of `mesaj.as_string()` already includes the From and To headers.  So those headers are duplicated.

Comment: ı didnt get it. is that the reason gmail perceiveing as spam ?

Comment: Your error message already indicates duplicate headers as reason for classification. Syntactical checks, e. g. your example, are used by spam filters to check if an email is valid or not, because spammers often dont get it right. I mean, more than one "From" and "To" header is suspicious, in the eyes of a spam filter, isn't it?